# Where are logs written when running Protractor2/Jasmine2 specs in parallel (shardTestFiles)?

Tags: javascript, selenium-webdriver, protractor, jasmine2.0

I'm looking to run some specs in parallel (eg. `shardTestFiles: true`) on Protractor 2.1.0 and Jasmine 2.2.1. The specs are running just fine, but I have some logging in place that I really need when it's done, that is not being displayed. I'm only getting the simple "..F" output from the tests (even with custom reporter set up).

In the case of sharded tests, where are logs written to, and how can I access them? Best case would be to output to a file.